# calculating rotating partners, 2 teams of 3 people for 5 rounds

Tags: mathematics

I want to make player sheets for 6 players (grouped into two teams of three players) on a rotating basis for 5 rounds.  It seems that 5 people will play the same player 3 times, 2 times and one time twice throughout the 5 rounds and one person will play each player 2 times for the 5 rounds.

Comment: What are the specific requirements? Do the teams change, for example? Why would one arrangement be better than another?

Comment: There's no way to make every pair teammates exactly twice out of five rounds. There are 10 ways to make 2 teams of 3, so playing 10 rounds will make every pair teammates exactly 4 times.